# Regex: Put the content of mutiple html tags into a single html tag

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

```
<p class="mb-40px">Decisive too, of
<p class="mb-40px">otherwise, it was the opportunity to
<p class="mb-40px">acquire what were to be two pillars
<p class="mb-40px">fundamentals of his intellectual formation:
<p class="mb-40px">Latin and virtually none of the Greek
<p class="mb-40px">written down, they were the subject of daily commentary on Apollo.</p>
```

**Must Become:**

```
<p class="mb-40px">Decisive too, of otherwise, it was the opportunity to acquire what were to be two pillars fundamentals of his intellectual formation: Latin and virtually none of the Greek written down, they were the subject of daily commentary on Apollo.</p>
```

**My regex is not very good:**

**Find:** `(<p class="mb-40px">)(.*?\s+\n)[\s\S]*?</p>`

**Replace by:** `\1$0\3`

Comment: Is the text always the same in the whole file : `<p class="mb-40px">` ? Is the number of lines different for each occurrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply search (with Regex) for:

```
([^>])(\r\n)(<p class="mb-40px">)
```

And replace with (note the space after `\1` and a space.

This will find all ***`<p class="mb-40px">`*** tags (that don't come after another tag, so not the first one.)

[image]

Comment: almost good. But I have a full html code. I must select this particular tag from the beginning, othewise will modify all my html tags

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I only select/remove the ```<p class="mb-40px">``` tag.

Comment: Your code will only work if the tag is found at the beginning of the file, which is not the case.

Comment: Got it. I went by the example without the context. I'll change it to ```([^>])(\r\n)(<p class="mb-40px">)``` replace with a ```\1``` and a space. I think that would work.

Comment: Not yet - what if it follows another tag that is not `<p>`.

Comment: The negative lookbehind is not for ```<p>``` but for ```>```. Don't all tags end with that?

Comment: The problem is that in the actual html, your regex cannot find anything on search. The strange thing is that, if I copy all the html content into another empty files, txt or html, your Regex works great and succeeded to make the Find and Replace.

Comment: It's probably because difference in line break type, the original HTML file doesn't have both type of line break markers. Try changing ```(\r\n)``` to ```(\n)``` or ```(\r)```

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `([^>])\s+(<p class="mb-40px">)`
- Replace with: `\1\x20`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Regex cannot do concatenate a variable number of lines, this is more
suited to a programming language than regex.

My solution requires concatenating two lines at a time, so you will
need to do "Replace All" as many times as required until the replacement
will fail.

This is the complicated search string :

Find what : `^<p class="mb-40px">(.*(?<!p>))\R^<p class="mb-40px">(.*?(?<!p>))$`
Replace with : `<p class="mb-40px">\1 \2`
Search mode : Regular expression without ". matches newline".

To understand how this works, see the breakdown of the terms in
[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YS9XfE/1).

Reference :
[Regex for string not ending with given suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398471/regex-for-string-not-ending-with-given-suffix).

[image]

Comment: doesn't work. Try this text for testing. https://pastebin.com/ybrgbM77